# Why isn't my content type drop-down selection available on my custom list form?

Tags: content-type

Please forgive my SharePoint ignorance. I needed to make a field read-only on the edit form which required me to use a custom list form. Now another roadblock...the content type selector is gone. Is there a way to have it on the form?

Comment: I found a work around posted here using javascript, tested and it works fine...http://kitmenke.com/blog/2009/06/02/make-a-text-field-read-only-on-editformaspx-without-spd/